# How to realize the conversion animation of two LineSegments in Three.js

Tags: three.js, visualization, line-segment

I have a model, which is composed of LineSegments. Then this model has two states. I know the coordinates of the points of these two states. How can I realize the animation of these two state transitions in Three.js?

any demo or guidece both are useful,thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

all. I have solved my problem. Because I know the position change of the vertex of the line segment, I choose to redraw the line segment several times to solve this problem. Each time you redraw, you will change the position based on the previous one to achieve the effect of animation. This may not be efficient, but it can solve the problem.
And if you have more solutions, I would appreciate it.